# jQuery drop-down menu doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, css

guys,
I'm JavaScript/jQuery rookie and now I'm learning the basis using a Udemy video tutorial, which I bought recently. Everything so far was good (except the lector thinks that the student already has a strong OOP knowledge?!).
Unfortunately I can't handle my last task. I checked for more than two hours for an error and never found it. Here's the code which I merged into one file to make it easier for you to track everything. The goal is to hover the mouse on the link "You have logged in as:" and the hidden menu
"My account
Profile
Settings
Log out"
to appear. Without jQuery the menu is on it's place, but obviously there's something wrong within the jQuery code.
Any help will be accepted with great regard!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
  h2 {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .profile-menu {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;

  }

  .submenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #aadd23;
    background: beige;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 7px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);

    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;

    display: none;
  }

  .submenu.active {
    display: block;
  }

  .submenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #345;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .submenu a:hover {
    background: #eee;
  }
</style>  

</head>
<body>

<h2>jQuery</h2>

<ul class="profile-menu">
   <li><a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">You have logged in as:</a> 
   </li>
   <ul class="profile-submenu submenu">
          <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { <br>
  $('[data-trigger = "dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function() { 
      var submenu = $(this).parent().find('.submenu');     
      submenu.addClass('active');                              

    } ); 
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.next()` and not `.find()` since your `.submenu` is not a child of the li, but a sibling.

```
$(this).parent().next('.submenu');
```

*Note*

`<ul>` should never be a direct child of another `<ul>`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
      var submenu = $(this).parent().next('.submenu');
      submenu.addClass('active');

    });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-menu {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #aadd23;
  background: beige;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 7px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #345;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  width: 300px;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>jQuery</h2>

<ul class="profile-menu">
  <li><a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">You have logged in as:</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="profile-submenu submenu">
    <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

**Correct html**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-trigger="dropdown"]').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var submenu = $(this).next('.submenu');
    submenu.addClass('active');

  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile-menu {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.submenu {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #aadd23;
  background: beige;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 7px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.submenu.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
  color: #345;
  text-shadow: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  width: 300px;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>jQuery</h2>

<ul class="profile-menu">
  <li><a class="profile-menu-trigger" data-trigger="dropdown" href="#">You have logged in as:</a>
    <ul class="profile-submenu submenu">
      <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, m-r Andersen. 
It runs now! Obviously I have to learn much more about jQuery - it really differs from Vanilla JS. Moreover I realize now that my error is in HTML code - I haven't put the closing li tag at the proper place and in reality those elements have been changed themselves to siblings :(   Always my empty haste...
After I fixed my HTML mistake, the first case - with .find() works too.
Anyway, what a shame for me! Such a stupid little error.
I was thinking I know HTML 5... ;)

Comment: @php2webdeveloper No problem, happy to help and remember that there is no shame of being knew to something or need help